Been to the UK in the past 10 years
I was issued a UK study visa in 2013, arrived the UK 1st January 2014 and left 1st January, 2016. Can I say I have been to the UK in the past 10 years?

Objectively you have. Who is asking you this, and why are you confused about what your answer should be?

How does your presence in the UK in the last 10 years relate to the [tag:luggage] and [tag:phuket] tags?

You were in the UK from 1 January 2014 until 1 January 2016.  2016 was only 8 years (and 3 months) ago, so you were definitely in the UK within the past 10 years.

Can I say I have been to the UK in the past 10 years?

Yes
